# Why am i not getting the proper output?

Tags: c

```
   int*func();
   int main()
    {
    int i;
    int *ptr;
    ptr=func();
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    printf("%d ",*ptr);
    ptr++;
    }
    }

     int* func()
    {
    int arr[10];
    int i;
    for( i=0;i<10;i++)
    arr[i]=i+1;
    return arr;
    }
```

Why i am not getting my output as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10??

I am returning the address of the array from func() but
 i am still getting junk values.

Answer (score 1):

Wow - aggressive downvoting! Give the new person a chance folks!

The answer is "scope". If you compile with gcc, you get a very obvious warning:

```
C:\tmp>gcc test.c
test.c: In function `func':
test.c:22: warning: function returns address of local variable
```

The local variable is lost when the function exits and its memory allocation cleaned up.

If you want to return an array from a function you have to `malloc` it to create a non-local memory allocation and then return the pointer.

Comment: I think the aggressive down-voting is probably due to the fact that there are many duplicate questions on this topic already, so the OP presumably hasn't done any research prior to posting.

Comment: apart from malloc cant i use anything else??

Comment: Yes, change `int arr[10];` to `static int arr[10];`, [take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/q/572547/1606345)

Comment: I know the meaning of "SCOPE" but totally lost it in this problem.

Comment: After changing arr[10] to static if i add a new function func1() in my program which prints all the elements of a array and call it from the func() so whether it will be able to print the elements??

Comment: I strongly suggest you **don't** use `static` as a way of working around this problem - it's a bad habit to get into and it results in code that is neither thread-safe nor re-entrant.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a pointer to a local variable, which results in undefined behaviour.

The most common way to deal with functions that return arrays is to pass in the array from the caller, e.g. fixed version of your code:

```
void func(int arr[]);

int main()
{
    int arr[10];

    func(arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);

    return 0;
}

void func(int arr[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        arr[i] = i + 1;
}
```